# how to select data from a JSON file in python?

Tags: python, json

I have a JSON file like that:

```
[
{
"course": "CMPT 102 D1", 
"instructor": "hamarneh", 
"students": [
  "axc5", 
  "csf10", 
  "ctu1", 
  "nmw15", 
  "nsm12", 
  "ppy1", 
  "qtg13", 
  "tim1", 
  "tkd10", 
  "vhm8", 
  "vsv1", 
  "wps1", 
  "xup12", 
  "yqt6"
], 
"title": "Scientific Cmpt.Prgm"
}]
```

and here is my code in python:

```
import json
json_data=open('jsonfile')
data=json.load(json_data)
print(data['students'])
```

but it shows an error:

```
   print(data['students'])
   TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

please help!

And another question:
Assume that the JSON file contains many courses with the structure like above. How can I do something like:

```
Select students, count(course) as course_number from tblstudent
group by students
```

Comment: Print 'data' and see how it looks. I bet it's a list of dicts, not one dict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your JSON contains a *list*, with one dictionary in it; there are two square brackets, `[` and `]`, around the dictionary.

Select the first element:

```
print(data[0]['students'])
```

Quick demo:

```
>>> print(data)
[{'instructor': 'hamarneh', 'course': 'CMPT 102 D1', 'title': 'Scientific Cmpt.Prgm', 'students': ['axc5', 'csf10', 'ctu1', 'nmw15', 'nsm12', 'ppy1', 'qtg13', 'tim1', 'tkd10', 'vhm8', 'vsv1', 'wps1', 'xup12', 'yqt6']}]
>>> print(data[0]['students'])
['axc5', 'csf10', 'ctu1', 'nmw15', 'nsm12', 'ppy1', 'qtg13', 'tim1', 'tkd10', 'vhm8', 'vsv1', 'wps1', 'xup12', 'yqt6']
```

Note that you could have spotted this yourself with a quick print of just `data`.

If this was a list of multiple courses and you need to count per-student, set up a dictionary keyed on students, containing integers. Using [`collections.defaultdict()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) makes that a little easier:

```
from collections import defaultdict

courses_per_student = defaultdict(int)

for course in data:
    for student in course['students']:
        courses_per_student[student] += 1
```

Comment: oh. Thank you. I am very new to JSON. How about if I want to count the number courses each student take as the sql query above?